# M-Audio Keystation 49 MK3, additional keys for FL studio

Tags: keyboard, fl-studio

Is there any way to make them work?
Yeah, including volume bar and pitch \ modulation wheels
Would be really convenient to actually use them for what they were made for. Thanks in advance!